# how to write out log during parallel computation? how to debug parallel computation?

Tags: r, debugging, parallel-processing

I found if there are more than one print function during the parallel computation, only the last on will display on the console. So I set outfile option and hope I can get the result of every print. Here is the R code:

```
cl <- makeCluster(3, type = "SOCK",outfile="log.txt") 

abc <<- 123

clusterExport(cl,"abc")

clusterApplyLB(cl, 1:6,  
         function(y){
                     print(paste("before:",abc));
                     abc<<-y;
                     print(paste("after:",abc));
         }
)
stopCluster(cl)
```

But I just get three records:

```
starting worker for localhost:11888 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
[1] "index: 3"
[1] "before: 123"
[1] "after: 2"
Type: EXEC 
[1] "index: 6"
[1] "before: 2"
[1] "after: 6"
Type: DONE
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're only getting the output from one worker in log.txt.  I've often wondered if that could happen, because when you specify `outfile="log.txt"`, each of the workers will open log.txt for appending and then call `sink`. Here is the code that is executed by the worker processes when `outfile` is not an empty string:

```
## all the workers log to the same file.
outcon <- file(outfile, open = "a")
sink(outcon)
sink(outcon, type = "message")
```

This makes me nervous because I'm not certain what might happen with all of the workers opening the same file for appending at the same time. It may be OS or file system dependent, and it might explain why you're only getting the output from one worker.

For this reason, I tend to use `outfile=""`, in which case this code isn't executed, allowing the output operations to happen normally without redirecting them with the `sink` function. However, on Windows, you won't see the output if you're using Rgui, so use Rterm instead.

There shouldn't be a problem with multiple print statements in a task, but if you didn't set `outfile`, you shouldn't see any output since all output is redirected to /dev/null in that case.

Comment: I would like to add, that <outfile="log.txt"> works quite good. Of course, it happens that sometimes subsequent messages will overlap, because all nodes are accessing it simultaneously, but this still allows for some kind of monitoring, for example, the progress of calculations.